# Error al intentar importar un archivo .DPM de oracle usando impd

Tags: oracle

El error que me presenta es al ejecutar el siguiente comando:

`impdp system/4MkiujN4@ORCL directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=xxdatabase_oracle.dmp`

Me da este error:

> Import: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on MiÚ Oct 18 10:20:27 2023
> Version 19.3.0.0.0
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
>
> Conectado a: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
> ORA-39002: operaci¾n no vßlida
> ORA-39405: El pump de datos de Oracle no soporta la importaci¾n de una base de datos de origen con la versi¾n 37 de TSTZ a una base de datos de destino con la versi¾n 32 de TSTZ.

¿Qué debo hacer para lograr la restauración de la base de datos?